# Get facebook creation date, or first post date with JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, api, date

I have been reading for the past hour, but have only found php solutions with **FQL**, unless I'm blind, or have been reading wrong, I can't seem to find a solution for this with javascript.

I need to use javascript because I'm processing this information front end for an application running on a csv file that's uploaded.

I have found many posts stating how to do it with fql, but nothing else.

Either the first post date, or the creation date is fine, both are close enough in my case.

Does anyone have any tips for this?

Comment: Why don't you make the FQL call from Javascript?

Comment: I thought it was only for PHP, I couldn't find any examples, I'm not amazing with javascript, you wouldn't be able to give me an example would you @Igy ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/ – where it says `GET /fql?q=…`, you just use FB.api to make the call, leaving out the `GET` part.

Comment: Can you get post information WITHOUT a token? @CBroe

Comment: Who said anything about tokens?

Comment: Well, getting the post date, I get a 'Signiture required' error message (104), hence the post title, that's what I'm trying to get, but couldn't get it because of the error @CBroe

Comment: Well, then you should get a token first. (What kind of permissions you need to access what kind of data is usually described in the docs.)